# How to use an entry in an array to call a different array entry

Tags: matlab, variables

I've looked at a few other questions but I couldn't come up with an answer, I'm relatively new to MatLab (but not programming) so I apologize if it's a duplicate.

I'm sure the title isn't very clear so here's an example:

I have an array, say `name = ['Jack';'Jill'];`. The elements in this array reference other arrays, such as:

```
Jack.income = 31000;
Jack.car = 1;
Jill.income = 55000;
Jill.car = 0;
```

Now, I would like to use `name` to pull data from the other arrays, such as:

`data = name(1).income`, which should return `31000`, or `data = name(2).car`, which should return `0`.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much,

Eric

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off using an array of structs (or making your own person object perhaps):

```
people(1).name = 'Jack';
people(1).income = 31000;
people(1).car = 1;
people(2).name = 'Jill';
people(2).income = 55000;
people(2).car = 0;
```

Now you can generate a list of names like this (see [cell arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html) and [comma separated lists](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html)):

```
names = {people.name};
```

which you can convert into an index like this (see [logical indexing](http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2008/01/28/logical-indexing/) and [ismember](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html)):

```
ind = ismember(names, 'Jack');
```

and then finally extract someone's income:

```
people(ind).income
```

Comment: Agreed. By the way, structed array is the fastest container datatype (in the sense of often element extraction/recording). Neither tables, not cell arrays are good.